# Download Registered ML model and use inside synapse analytics

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, azure-synapse, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to deploy an ml model from ml studio inside synapse analytics, but can't find any documentation/guidance on what I do.

Essentially, these are the steps I would like to undertake:

1. Train an ML model in ML studio and register it in the model registry
2. Wrangle data inside synapse analytics
3. Download/reference the ml model inside synapse analytics to predict the wrangled data

Any guidance on how I could approach the problem? deploying the ml model to an endpoint URL is not an option as it's too expensive and overkill for the approach I am trying to implement.

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an Azure ML linked service in Synapse (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/machine-learning/quickstart-integrate-azure-machine-learning).
2. Download your registered model artifacts to your local machine.
3. Use Azure Storage Explorer software to upload the artifacts you downloaded to Azure datalake. For this, you need to create an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 linked service in Synapse. Then, use the following code in Synapse to mount a specified folder in datalake, e.g. 'tmp'. Note that you should upload the model artifacts to "/tmp/user/trusted-service-user" in the datalake.

   ```
   mssparkutils.fs.unmount('/tmp')

   mssparkutils.fs.mount(
       "abfss://tmp@some_lake.dfs.core.windows.net",
       "/tmp",
       {"linkedService": "some_linked_svc_to_datalake"}
   )
   ```
4. Use the following code in case you've used pyspark.ml.PipelineModel when training the model. Otherwise, you can use e.g. joblib to load the model.

   ```
   from notebookutils.mssparkutils import azureML
   from pyspark.ml import PipelineModel
   from azureml.core.model import Model

   linkedService_name = "some_linked_svc_to_azureml"
   ws = azureML.getWorkspace(linkedService_name)
   model_name = 'some_model_name'
   model_obj = Model(ws, model_name)
   model = PipelineModel.load(model_obj.download(exist_ok=True))
   ```